# Swift: use of unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I keep getting error "Use of unresolved identifier" with class name `SomeService`.

It's declared in `SomeService.swift`

```
import UIKit
class SomeService: NSObject {
    ...
}
```

Project and tests are compiling nevertheless with these errors most of the time. When I try to go to SomeService declaration, errors disappear for a minute or two. Debugger recognizes these object instances.

*Target membership is fine. No linker warnings. No other entities with same name. I've tried to delete and create this file again without any luck. Error began appearing after converting project to Swift 3 with Xcode 8.*

Same happening with other classes as well, but rarely. Crashes of com.apple.dt.SourceKitService are irrelevant — issue happens when SourceKitService isn't crashing too. Xcode syntax highlighter crashes are very rare and probably aren't causing it.

Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT: If compiled, app works fine, tests are passing, no other anomalies

EDIT 2: I've deleted DerivedData a few times, tried public, open and even @objc class modifiers.

Comment: Does the compiler point to any lines of code with this error or is it simply an arbitrary crash, displaying this error?

Comment: Compiler points to lines that mention SomeService in most of the files (not only open ones) saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'SomeService'"

Comment: Hmmmm... Only thing I could think of would be to make the class public. Since you say the Targets are correct. Maybe for some reason other classes have issue with referencing it.

Comment: Yes, I tried open, public and even @objc

Comment: So you are saying that the very same code sometimes compiles and sometimes doesn't???

Comment: Yes. However it compiles most of the time.

Comment: BTW, Matt, it's pretty obvious why. Xcode has different sources of errors. Some errors/suggestions could be invalidated by successful compilation. IDE syntax checker that is spawning wrong errors about "unresolved identifiers" sometimes might be faster than compiler, which invalidates them. So Xcode's IDEBuildSystemActivityReporter might stop compilation because it has too many errors already.